# Is 微话题 an acceptable translation of “hashtag”?

Tags: translation

A saw a translation of spoken English saying: `hashtag fun` to something like:

> 微话题 乐趣

I’m not seeing a lot of results for `微话题` online.

As far as I know hashtag is usually translated as 话题 or 标签 or some combination of both.

Assuming people don’t go around saying things like “hashtag [...]” in Chinese & if someone said “话题...” or “标签...” it probably wouldn’t be readily understood - then perhaps 微话题 is a better option.

微话题 could be considered as overly specific, as a weibo topic.

This is all speculation though.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the function of hashtag is to highlight related topics the post belong to, then, '话题标签' would be an accurate description

Comment: I would suggest use "话题" instead of "微话题". for disambiguate, "微博话题" or "推特话题" may be a better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「微話題」is literally *microblog discussion topic*, where「微」comes from「微博」(*microblog*). Note that **Weibo** is a proper noun also using these two characters, but before Weibo was invented「微博」was just a generic word meaning *microblog*.

Netizens put the discussion topic (話題) between **two** hashtags, much the same way the single twitter hashtag is used (possibly because Chinese doesn't use word spacings). In the sense that it is an announcement of a discussion topic on some board/forum/social media then translating it as *hashtag* is fine, but this translation may be confusing for people coming from the PRC if one uses it to point to "western" apps/media that are possibly banned or relatively unknown/unpopular in the PRC such as Twitter and Facebook.

See also the Baidu article [微话题](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BE%AE%E8%AF%9D%E9%A2%98/2799122).